# File Recreation

Tags: command-line, files

There is a game that a play and as a result of playing it there are these files that appear in my terminal. So what I did was rename those files and move them into one directory because when they get downloaded onto my computer initially the names of the files are a bit daunting. Well when I revisit and launch the game again the files, with the initial names, reappear in my directory. And the files that I renamed are still where I put them. Why would the website redownload those files onto my computer even though they still exists just with different names and in a different directory?

Comment: You can't just move files somewhere and expect the programs that use them to magically know what you did. That's like you probably wouldn't know how to get to work, if someone took your car, repainted it and put it in your neighbors garage. 
Programs usually depend on specific file names and locations. If you are in luck maybe there is a configuration file allowing you to set a location, but if not, I am afraid you will have to live with those files.

Comment: Which web app is it? Which version of Ubuntu do you use? To answer your question 'Why does the web app redownload files?' we need this information.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 is what i use

Answer (score 2):

> Why would the website redownload those files onto my computer even though they still exists just with different names and in a different directory?

Because it doesn't know. Usually programs look for files they expect in only a very limited number of places, and then assume the file is gone. There is no trace to point the application at the new location of a moved file.

Perhaps the applicatin always downloads to the current directory. If so, then changing the current working directory to the directory where you moved those files might help. But it would be *very* helpful if you'd actually indicate *what* program you are running which does that downloading.